# Is it OK for hashCode to return different values between different runs?

Tags: java, hash, non-deterministic

I'm trying to learn the full story behind `hashCode`. In most implementations `hashCode` is fully deterministic, like in `StringUTF16` class:

```
public static int hashCode(byte[] value) {
    int h = 0;
    int length = value.length >> 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        h = 31 * h + getChar(value, i);
    }
    return h;
}
```

I think that such implementation is not great: it's easy to construct examples which have the same hashCode. For example, a user of a system can submit exactly the words with the same `hashCode` for DOS attack. It doesn't work with `String`, since it implements `Comparable` (and `HashMap` is an over-hacked mess), but it won't help with classes which don't implement `Comparable`.

A better approach seems to use a random factor (instead of `31`), so that the user don't know how to construct bad examples (and it also has some theoretical properties), like this:

```
class ImmutableArray{
    // Note static keyword. It guarantees that for the same run all objects use the same x.
    private static final int x = generateRandomPrime();

    int[] values;

    public int hashCode() {
        int res = 5;
        for (int v : values) {
            res = res * x + v;
        }
        return res;
    }

    ...

}
```

Now, my question: is there anything bad about this implementation? The only problem I can see is that it will return different hashCodes for different runs of the program, but I can't imagine a concrete scenario where something can go wrong.

Comment: think about Hash based `Map`. `HashMap`s would never work. Also how do you even plan on mounting an attack when the main purpose of the `hash` is for storage and retrieval and not one wayness

Comment: @Ryotsu, are you talking about some persistent `Map`? In this case hashCode should be something else whatsoever, like MD5.

Comment: @dhyukha the size of md5 and its running time will kill any application that uses it

Comment: also have a look at its contract on [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()] , it says that function should return the same hash values on multiple calls and also if the objects are equal.

Comment: @Ryotsu why wouldn’t a HashMap work in this case? The map would be created with a constant random value (initialized upon runtime) and will remain that factor through the program’s lifetime. I only see this being an issue if the map preserves hashcodes through serialization? Also, each hashcode function call *would* be the same. The value is constant, it doesn’t change each call, according to the OP’s code.

Comment: @Ryotsu, What I suggest doesn't violate the contract: for the same run equal objects have the same `hashCode` (the fact that you call `equals` on them means that they belong to the same run). Whether it should be true between different runs is unclear and is the essence of my question.

Comment: @dyukha whoopsie, I'm sorry, didn't notice that `static`

Comment: @Ryotsu, Sorry that I didn't make it clear (my first version was longer, with initialization block, and it was clear that `x` is statically initialized).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is NOT a requirement that `hashCode` gives the same values in different JVMs.  For example, the `HashMap` class does not persist the `hashCode` values of the map's keys when it is serialized.  Instead, the `hashCode` values are recomputed when the map is deserialized.

The only potential problem I can see is that recomputing the `hashCode` on each call is inefficient.  You can address that by computing it lazily (like `String::hashCode` does for example).

But if you implement lazy `hashCode` calculation, you *need* to declare the field where you store it as `transient`.  Otherwise, the `hashCode` value in a de-persisted key instance won't `==` the `hashCode` value computed for another instance that is "equal" to the key.  (In other words, the hashcode / equals contract is broken!)  This will lead to lookup failure.

If you do this properly, there should be no problem vis-a-vis serialization of `HashMap`.  For example, you could follow the approach of `String::hashCode` and use zero as the cached `hashCode` value which means "the code needs to be calculated" to the `hashCode()` method.

<sup>(If your key class doesn't have a field to hold a cached `hashCode` value, the problem with persisting that value doesn't arise.)</sup>

---

The other thing to note is that *modifying* the key class to implement `Comparable` would be another defense against DOS-based attacks.  In your example class, the implementation of the `compareTo` method is simple.  Note that the ordering that you implement doesn't need to be semantically meaningful.  It just needs to be stable and consistent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you please clarify the `volatile` part? Without it, in the worst I will have minor performance problems (since I need to recalculate `hashCode` again), right? The problems are minor, since the number of recalculations is limited by the number of CPUs.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Without volatile: there are only 2 options: 1) A thread sees the field as a calculated value; since there is only one way to calculate the value and returns it, it must be correct. 2) A thread sees it as a non-calculated value; then it computes it (correctly), updates the field and then returns the computed (correct) value. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry ... my mistake ... I was *thinking* of `transient` and writing `volatile`.  Corrected.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see this as much of an issue unless you get into specialized applications of serialization. In most scenarios, the way you have it setup is basically equivalent to adding an arbitrary `31` value as far as the runtime is concerned (the value does not change).

Though, through reflection 'trickery' you could potentially alter the value and throw the whole system off track (think `setAccessible` and modifier flags).

In the event there's a setup that depends on hash-codes and consistency when objects are serialized and transferred to different environments, I see greater chance for problems. The way hash-codes compare between the two separate environments are highly likely to differ when they actually should not).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I assume that reflection is not an issue (imagine that I'm a server and clients can only send me requests).
I think that serialization which uses hashCode is a bad idea, since serialization is a form of public constructor and hashCode is a very-implementation detail. In this case class should design its own `hashCodeForSerialization` with its documentation (or properly document its `hashCode`, which prevents me from using randomization).